# Conversion to Dalvik Unable to execute dex:Java heap space and Unhandled event loop exception error in creating map activity

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, memory

I am facing this error: unable to execute dex:Java heap space and unhandled event loop exception in eclipse after when I am trying to use map api v2.then it also prompt a internal error dialog and show "An out of memory has occurred".

I am beginner and have no idea to solve this.
I followed this tutorial for using api: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup--mobile-15771
I found some previous almost similar question like but not worked.I already set my dx.bat file defaultXmx=-Xmx1624M.may be this case is different.please help.

Comment: can you show logcat?

Comment: logcat is showing same error. no other explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to your eclipse directory and find eclipse.ini file.
overwrite the following code

```
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

to this

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1048m
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it works)

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx1048m
```

to

```
-Xms1048m
-Xmx2048m
```